# Ipyleaflet: How to make multiple maps move simultaneously

Tags: python, maps, geojson, ipyleaflet

Is it possible to create multiple map frames using Ipyleaflet that each show different data, but if you move or zoom on one of the maps, all the other maps do the same movement?

For example: I have a GeoJson file which I want to visualize on a map and the file has several columns of data which I would like to see at the same time for interpretation purposes. One column has the amount of people working in a certain profession and another column has the percentage of people in a region working that same profession, it would be very handy if I could see these numbers visualized on two maps which always have the same map view and behave exactly the same if you interact with one of the maps.

Thanks in advance for the answer!